# Ignoring F403 rule in Flake8 3.7.x also ignores rule E402

Tags: python, flake8

I am trying to ignore few pep-8 rules by using the inline noqa feature provided by flake8. I have two errors: E402, and F403 on a single line. If I add #noqa: F403 to ignore that specific rule on the line causing the error, then flake8 also ignores the E402 rule.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Are there any other rules which have the same behavior, and might cause non trivial problems?

Tried doing something similar with other rules as well. Same things happen for E722, and E731. Ignoring E731, ignores E722 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug in flake8](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/552)

It will be fixed in flake8 3.8.x by this patch: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/merge_requests/331

the root of the problem is both `flake8` and the underlying `pycodestyle` implement handling for `noqa` (pycodetsyle doesn't have support for individual code exclusion) -- the fix is to have only `flake8` do that